# How can we change the ringer mode in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, permissions, permission-denied

Runtime error when I try to change ringer mode to normal.i am using dependency service to call audio manager in android in xamarin form but code runs without error when the ringer mode change to silent ( maybe it's already silent)

Comment: What is the specific exception?  Where is the code you are using to do this?

Comment: @Mr, Any update?have solved your issue? If not, Please see the following code about changing ringer mode.

Answer (score 0):

About changing ringer mode, you can follow these steps.

1.define a interface in Xamarin.Forms PCL.

```
 public interface IChangeRingModeService
{
    void changeRingModeToNormal();
    void changeRingModeToVibrate();

    void changeRingModeToSilent();

}
```

2. In Android project, implement this interface in Mainactivity.cs, please don't forget register dependency

   ```
   [assembly: Dependency(typeof(MainActivity))]

   namespace App4.Droid
   {
   [Activity(Label = "App4", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize| ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
   public class MainActivity : 
      global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IChangeRingModeService
    {
   AudioManager am;      
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
       ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;


       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

       global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
       LoadApplication(new App());                            

   }

   public void changeRingModeToVibrate()
   {
       am = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
       am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Vibrate;
   }

   public void changeRingModeToNormal()
   {
       am = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
       am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Normal;
   }

   public void changeRingModeToSilent()
   {
       am = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
       am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Silent;
   }}}
   ```
3. call this method in click event.

   ```
    private void Button1licked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DependencyService.Get<IChangeRingModeService>().changeRingModeToVibrate();
   }

   private void Button2licked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DependencyService.Get<IChangeRingModeService>().changeRingModeToNormal();
   }

   private void Button3licked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DependencyService.Get<IChangeRingModeService>().changeRingModeToSilent();
   }
   ```